# Powershell script to remove groups from users

Tags: powershell, office365

I found this script to remove groups from a single user but i'm afraid to try it in my environment:
Question - is there a test lab online where i can run these scripts without breaking my own environment? Also can someone with more scripting/powershell knowledge verify that this is safe to run if i want to remove groups from a user? I was instructed to run the script with an argument after it i.e. c:/sripts/removegroups.ps1 username@domain" is that correct?

```
$user = $args[0] if (!$args[0]) {

} $mailbox=get-mailbox $user

$dgs= Get-DistributionGroup

foreach($dg in $dgs){

$DGMs = Get-DistributionGroupMember -identity $dg.Identity
foreach ($dgm in $DGMs){
if ($dgm.name -eq $mailbox.name){

    write-host 'User Found In Group' $dg.identity
      Remove-DistributionGroupMember $dg.Name -Member $user
}
}
}
```

Comment: You can see this link for Microsoft virtual labs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtuallabs/bb467605.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `$WhatIfPreference` to `$true`, and all the commands in the script should display what would have happened had they been run for real. This is (slightly) easier than modifying the script commands one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *whatif* switch on the Remove-DistributionGroupMember command

```
$user = $args[0] if (!$args[0]) {

} $mailbox=get-mailbox $user

$dgs= Get-DistributionGroup

foreach($dg in $dgs){

$DGMs = Get-DistributionGroupMember -identity $dg.Identity
foreach ($dgm in $DGMs){
if ($dgm.name -eq $mailbox.name){

   write-host 'User Found In Group' $dg.identity
      Remove-DistributionGroupMember $dg.Name -Member $user -Whatif
}
}
}
```

The WhatIf switch instructs the command to simulate the actions that it would take on the object. By using the WhatIf switch, you can view what changes would occur without having to apply any of those changes. You don't have to specify a value with the WhatIf switch.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998016(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Would it look something like this?

```
$WhatIfPreference = $true 
$user = $args[0] if (!$args[0]) {

} $mailbox=get-mailbox $user

$dgs= Get-DistributionGroup

foreach($dg in $dgs){

$DGMs = Get-DistributionGroupMember -identity $dg.Identity
foreach ($dgm in $DGMs){
if ($dgm.name -eq $mailbox.name){

write-host 'User Found In Group' $dg.identity
  Remove-DistributionGroupMember $dg.Name -Member $user
}
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, although I'd leave the first line out of the script and just execute it separately. When you're satisfied that the script works, execute `$WhatIfPreference = $false` and run the (unmodified) script once more.

Comment: Thanks Nathan I will give this a shot tomorrow and report back.

Answer (score 0):

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $WhatIfPreference = $true
PS C:\Windows\system32> $user = $args[0] if (!$args[0]) {
At line:1 char:18
+ $user = $args[0] if (!$args[0]) {
+                  ~~
Unexpected token 'if' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:33
+ $user = $args[0] if (!$args[0]) {
+                                 ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32> } $mailbox=get-mailbox $user
At line:1 char:1
+ } $mailbox=get-mailbox $user
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32> $dgs= Get-DistributionGroup
WARNING: By default, only the first 1000 items are returned. Use the ResultSize
 parameter to specify the number of items returned. To return all items,
specify "-ResultSize Unlimited". Be aware that, depending on the actual number
of items, returning all items can take a long time and consume a large amount
of memory. Also, we don't recommend storing the results in a variable. Instead,
 pipe the results to another task or script to perform batch changes.
PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32> foreach($dg in $dgs){
>>enter code here
>> $DGMs = Get-DistributionGroupMember -identity $dg.Identity
>> foreach ($dgm in $DGMs){
>> if ($dgm.name -eq $mailbox.name){
>>
>> write-host 'User Found In Group' $dg.identity
>>   Remove-DistributionGroupMember $dg.Name -Member $user
```

Comment: Didn't look to happy ... is there a better way to remove add a single user to multiple groups?